# How do I add 2 more songs to an already existing song in AS3 script in Flash?

Tags: flash, list, audio, actionscript

Can someone please, specifically and with a detailed example, as I'm a novice at Flash CS6 actionscript 3, explain to me how I can add 2 more songs to my player, and still control them with the current play and pause buttons?

Many thanks!

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var mySound:Sound = new heyjude();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void{
lastPosition = myChannel.position;  
myChannel.stop();
}

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void{
myChannel.stop()
myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to have those more sound files in your player? Want to play one after one or any one at random or any one by condition or all at once

Comment: Like a jukebox, I would like to have 3 songs, but also have a choice to select anyone of them in no specific order. Once the song reaches its end it should stop. For example clicking the title will begin to play that particular song, but if I click on another title it will begin to play that one instead. All the while still being able to use the same play and pause buttons. Thank you again for your help, Ande

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this sample code by just assumed there are four titles/title buttons and so four title channels. I am having a sound channel for title sound. I can stop or pause or play the sound with that. Simply says, I can control the title sound using `titleChannel`.

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var titleSound1:Sound = new TitleSound1();
var titleSound2:Sound = new TitleSound2();
var titleSound3:Sound = new TitleSound3();
var titleSound4:Sound = new TitleSound4();

var mySound:Sound = new heyjude();

var titleChannel:SoundChannel;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;

var lastPosition:Number = 0;

titleBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, title1Selected);
titleBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, title2Selected);
titleBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, title3Selected);
titleBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, title4Selected);

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

function title1Selected(e:MouseEvent){
    if(titleChannel != null) titleChannel.stop();
    titleChannel = titleSound1.play();
}

function title2Selected(e:MouseEvent){
    if(titleChannel != null) titleChannel.stop();
    titleChannel = titleSound2.play();
}

function title3Selected(e:MouseEvent){
    if(titleChannel != null) titleChannel.stop();
    titleChannel = titleSound3.play();
}

function title4Selected(e:MouseEvent){
    if(titleChannel != null) titleChannel.stop();
    titleChannel = titleSound4.play();
}

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void{
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;  
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void{
    myChannel.stop()
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
}
```

If you want to pause and resume the play of the title sound like other sound, then do the same like what you did to `myChannel` in the function `onClickPause` and `onClickPlay`.

Note: If you want to play a sound for an event(like background or during a blast or something else) and if that event occurs very often, then don't hesitate to have a `SoundChannel` instance for that sound to control that sound.

Comment: Many thanks Moorthy! I really appreciate your time and effort. I'm trying an alternative method now to see if this would also work, and will try your solution as well. Wish I had your expertise abilities!;-)